# How to retrieve input parameter values from a C language function

Tags: c, eclipse

I have a program contains 2 function;

```
  int computation (int a, int b) 

 {

 ..

..

 ..

 }

 void computation2 (int v, int k, int c) 

{

..

..

}
```

I need to create a function that automatically retrieves the value of input variables for each function after it has been executed.
and show something like this:

- a = 52     -b = 4      -v = 41     -k = 53      -c = 12

-I need an automatic way that gets the values of the inputs of any function. if it exists

Comment: That does not exist. You can use `printf` to print their values.

Comment: no, I must not touch the function, I need an automatic way

Comment: You want to modify your program or create another program which will control the first program execution?

Comment: I want another program that retrieves the value of input variables and global variabe, automatic, that means it detects by itself the global variable and the variables entered in the functions and displays it, and that works for any program

Comment: in the function(s) that call the target functions,  Capture the variable values before making the actual call.  Otherwise, all knowledge about the variable values is 'lost'